# Cover up full space of div area with list items without breaking

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Not sure how to describe this. Instead following images might make it clear.

This is what I have:
[image]

And this is how I want to show it (check out full div area covered up):
[image]

HTML structure:

```
<ul class="block">
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/6f2t2bew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` tags have default display type of `list-item` which cause each `li` to start from a new line. As you show in your image you want third `li` to start not from the newline but from where the second `li` finsihed. For that set

```
.block li {
  display: inline
}
```

**Edit:** You are giving float left to `li`s which cause them to act like sort of block level and whole content of `li` start acting like a unit which tends to go to left. To avoid this remove float left as:
https://jsfiddle.net/6f2t2bew/1/

Also if you want more justification of text then apply `text-align: justify` to the parent `ul`.

Comment: I have updated my question with jsfiddle link. `display: inline` isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove `float: left` on your `li`? Of course use `display: inline;` on the same element as @user31782 suggested.

So your css for `.footer-top li` looks like:

```
.footer-top li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  position: relative;
  display: inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote 'clas' in the first line of your code. Try changing it to 'class'.

Comment: thanks for noticing. but that's not the thing i was looking for actually. this was just a typo in the question.